# What's the difference between BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)) and BorderRadius.circular(4)

Tags: flutter, dart

Both of that implementations are doing the same, which is rounding a `child` with a `BorderRadis`:

```
ClipRRect(
 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
 child: /*...*/
 )


ClipRRect(
 borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
 child: /*...*/
 )
```

is there a major difference between them, and what should I use?

Comment: it's the same, but each widget has it's own way to show up some thing

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I know they show the same thing on the UI but is there any performance difference between them? and which one is preferrable ?

Comment: I think there is no any difference between them, I've tried two of them before without and difference.
For me I prefer the first one, because maybe I want to change the radius for one of the corners, not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference, they are identical.

`BorderRadius.circular()` is just a convenience constructor.

The implementation of `.circular()` calls for `.all()` with `Radius.circular()`:

```
BorderRadius.circular(double radius) : this.all(
  Radius.circular(radius),
);
```